# How to draw overlapping images with varying offsets with GDI

Tags: .net, math, gdi

The math is eluding me on this one. I have an area of a specific size that can't change (say 100,100). Normally this contains a 'RigControl' image:

[image]

I'm looking to implement the facility to overlap a 'GameControl' image over the top of this with a variable, separate x and y offset percentage that can be negative. For instance, this would be with an x = 40 and y = 40 offset:

[image]

and this with x = -40 and y = -40 offset:

[image]

I could achieve the first with this code:

```vb
Dim nImg As New Bitmap(CInt(containerSize.Width + (containerSize.Width * Math.Abs(xOffsetPercentage) / 100)),
                        CInt(containerSize.Height + (containerSize.Height * Math.Abs(yOffsetPercentage) / 100)),
                            PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb)

Using g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(nImg)

    g.DrawImage(RigControlImg, New Rectangle(0, 0, containerSize.Width, containerSize.Height))

    g.DrawImage(GameControlImage, New Rectangle(CInt(containerSize.Width * xOffsetPercentage / 100),
                                            CInt(containerSize.Height * yOffsetPercentage / 100),
                                            containerSize.Width, containerSize.Height))

End Using
```

However, when I use negative numbers, it gets cut off like this:

[image]

I know why, of course: where x or y are negative, the RigControl Image's origin needs to be offset and the GameControl at 0,0. So, I reduced it to input, output tables, but can't discern the function to return these values (works for both x and y values, naturally):

| Offset | RigControl | GameControl |
| --- | --- | --- |
| -100 | 100 | 0 |
| 100 | 0 | 100 |
| -200 | 200 | 0 |
| 200 | 0 | 200 |

Really struggling with the maths on this one! Sure I'm going to kick myself when it's solved!

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. Solved it. I'm not sure this could be solved via an equation. The eventual answer was using a combination of `Math.Abs`, `Math.Min` and `Math.Max` in the end, to floor or max out negative numbers. Working code:

```vb
Dim nImg As New Bitmap(CInt(containerSize.Width + (containerSize.Width * Math.Abs(xOffsetPercentage) / 100)),
                    CInt(containerSize.Height + (containerSize.Height * Math.Abs(yOffsetPercentage) / 100)),
                        PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb)

Dim rigOffset As Point = New Point(Math.Abs(Math.Min(0, CInt(containerSize.Width * xOffsetPercentage / 100))),
                                Math.Abs(Math.Min(0, CInt(containerSize.Height * yOffsetPercentage / 100))))

Dim gameOffset As Point = New Point(Math.Abs(Math.Max(0, CInt(containerSize.Width * xOffsetPercentage / 100))),
                                Math.Abs(Math.Max(0, CInt(containerSize.Height * yOffsetPercentage / 100))))

Using g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(nImg)

g.DrawImage(RigControlImg, New Rectangle(rigOffset.X, rigOffset.Y, containerSize.Width, containerSize.Height))

g.DrawImage(GameControlImage, New Rectangle(gameOffset.X,
                                            gameOffset.Y,
                                            containerSize.Width, containerSize.Height))
End Using
```

Result:

[image]